# Control window size of on screen keyboard using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am running the command `osk` in a powershell script, which open the on-screen keyboard, whose size can be changed by dragging its corners.

I am looking for a command that will generate this window with a specific height and width. Is that possible?

Comment: There may be some dll hacks to re-adjust program window sizes, but I'm not knowledgeable enough in that to know them.  Based on the settings and lack of command-line arguments for `osk.exe`, you cannot re-size the keyboard in that way.

Comment: `osk` isn't actually a powershell command, it's just running the `osk.exe` program, the same as running `notepad` in powershell runs `notepad.exe`.

Comment: I was imagining some like this: osk | {something to resize normal windows}

Comment: Like @TheIncorrigible1 wrote, I don't think there's anything native. But from what I found, try running this script: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-the-position-and-size-54853527 and then execute the Function Set-Window to resize osk.